# How to include Unobtrusive Javascript in Visual Studio 2013 MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I was trying to do something similar as described in this website
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript
where I perform remote validation. I have turned on UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled and ClientValidationEnabled.  However, when I reach the following part of the code I cannot locate jquery.validate.min.js (locally) and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js. I have updated to the latest jquery version with NuGet but these files are not found anywhere.  Is there something I need to do? Am I missing something? The instructions about adding remote validation always assume that these files are present.

```
<head>
  <title>@View.Title</title>
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: It should be their in Script folder. have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to files on the net not on your local drive. 
Solution: download the files from the url into the script folder of your project and retry.

Comment: I downloaded the files but the remote validation does not kick in at all.  I have added the data annotation in the model, I have added the function in the controller, but it never gets called. I have followed the instructions to the letter. Up to this point I assumed that it was due to the missing jquery files but now that they are there I am not sure anymore.

Comment: I just realized that I have shown only one of the links that it is a prerequisite for the remote validation tutorial which is listed here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx)